# Counting And Monitoring How Much Queries My Script Used

Tags: query, wp-insert-post

I programmatically created 3000 posts using `wp_insert_post()` with three custom fields.

My hosting provider suspend me to 1 hour because they said I have exceeded 100,000 queries per hour limitation.

I can't understand how it happens. I mean how just inserting 3000 posts with 3 custom fields exceed 100,000 queries.

I never thoughts it is more than 40,000 queries.

Is they way to Counting And Monitoring How Much Queries My Script Used?

Note : It is a loop. So it is enough, if I can monitor which queries are run just for 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there happens more than single query behind the scene. They are both for getting some needed data and also for updating or creating or inserting data. Say for post terms `wp_insert_post()` get those data by query. So, where you're assuming that it should run 40,000 query it actually run more than that. [Please have look here](https://javorszky.co.uk/2014/08/19/what-happens-on-wp_insert_post/). This guy explained step by step beautifully how `wp_insert_post()` actually works.